# Methods of BigDecimal to go down scale and precision

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, floating-point

I need a method that go down the scale of a BigDecimal number created as variable

Example:

```
number1 = BigDecimal.new('154.4978')
number1 => 154.4978
```

now I want that number1 = 154.49. How I go down the scale?

Comment: `154.4978` rounded to two decimal places would be `154.50`; you're saying that you want to truncate, or "floor" the number to a specific number of decimal places?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried `#truncate`:

```
BigDecimal.new('154.4978').truncate(2) # => 154.49
```

It's all in the API documentation: http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/bigdecimal/1.8.7/BigDecimal:truncate

Comment: Shouldn't this be BigDecimal.new('154.4978').round(2) so that you end up with 154.50?  Please explain.

Comment: The OP is specifically asking for truncation, not rounding. He says he wants 154.4978 to become 154.49. Had he said he wanted it to be 154.50 then #round would have been appropriate.